# Sqoop Import command throwing error but it is working from terminal

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, sqoop, oozie

Below command is working fine from terminal but when I extecute it from Oozie it is throwing error.

```
bash
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://172.16.16.128:3306/employees -- username=hive --password=hive --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --query 'select * from employee.testtable where 1=1 AND $CONDITIONS' --m 1 --target-dir '/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/testtable' --hive-import --hive-table test.testtable --hive-drop-import-delims --hive-overwrite --hs2-url jdbc:hive2://hivehostname:10000/default;
```

`ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`

I have already put hive-jdbc driver in hadoop/lib, sqoop/lib and hive/lib directory. Sometimes it run perfectly but sometimes throw error.

I am unable to identify the behavior of the system because already put hive jdbc jar. why is it behaving like this. Please help me.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the command?

Comment: could you pls run the sqoop in bash with same use thats running Oozie? Looks like permission issue.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I have given full permission. Still falling the Job

Comment: hm, something is missing it seems. can you pls login using the user thats running Oozie demon in UNIX? And then try sqoop command. its not able to find jdbc drivers. also see if you have conflicting entries or multiple entries for jdbc in profile file so oozie user gets confused.

Comment: @Kousik Roy driver not found issue has been resolved, now it is throwing "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Iface
". I also found one thing sqoop only works on few data nodes not all but I have put same jars in all machines

Answer (score 0):

I have download below jars and push on all nodes into sqoop Lib locations then Issue got resolved.

hive-common-*.jar
hive-exec-*.jar
hive-service.jar

```
cd /usr/hdp/3.0.1.0-187/sqoop/lib
chmod 775 /usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-common-*.jar 
chmod 775 /usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-exec-*.jar 
chmod 775 /usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-service.jar
```